# Submitting a form in an https page

Tags: forms, ssl, action

I have a form in a HTTPS page. The action that was generated use the HTTPs too

```
https://foo.com/?ACT=140&...
```

However, when I tried testing submitting the form, it did not work.

I tried testing using the HTTP protocol

```
http://foo.com/?ACT=140&...
```

and it worked(albeit with a warning dialog showing me that it is unsafe).

Is this correct? Is ExpressionEngine unable to process action urls with the HTTPS protocol?

If so, how do I remedy this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it did not work' -- did you get any errors?

Comment: It seems to load non-https resources. My guess is that it cancelled the submit because of that. The page shown is http://foo.com/

Comment: Show us some code, Arvin

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the details of your install and project, this questions is pretty impossible to answer in my opinion.

First make sure you change `$config['site_url'] = "http://domain.com/";` to `$config['site_url'] = "/";` in your config file.

`$config['site_url'] = "//domain.com/";` may work also.

If that doesn't do it, you'll need to identify the exact resources that are loading with http:// and track backwards in the code to see how those URLs are generated. You'll then know your options.